# How to enforce minimum width of formatted string in C#

Tags: c#, .net, string, formatting

I have the following statement

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
string test = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}", now.Day, now.Month, now.Year, now.Hour);
```

This gives me:

```
test = "242200915"
```

But I'd like to have something like:

```
test = "2402200915"
```

So the question is, how can I enforce the string formatter to output each int with the width of 2 while padding with zeroes?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `string.Format("{0:000} {0:D3}", 7)`
to get `007 007`

And here is a useful overview on MSDN: [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)

Comment: You got in just before me, deleting my answer (p.s. I didn't know about 0:D3, nice one)

Answer (score 20):

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
string test = now.ToString("ddMMyyyyHH");
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just do

```
String test = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyHH");
```

You can format the numbers to be a certain width but this seems like more of what you want.

Comment: Probably because it's exactly the same thing someone else posted 3 minutes earlier.  But that's just a guess.

Comment: I actually modified it to clarify, it was actually posted at the exact same time.